# Does get() Parse query result do another db call?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

When I do .find() or first() on Parse (cloud-code or otherwise)  and get a results objects. If I then do .get(fieldName) on the result object does that do another db call and hence needs further asynchronous handling?  Or is the data now local? If so, how can I introspect the results object in the console without using .get()

Note I'm using the JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's local or it doesn't exist (if you specified to only find certain keys and you request a different one) so there is no additional network / database request.

Comment: Ah so what kind of object structure comes back? Why can't I introspect the fields of the results in the console? Or how?

Comment: Parse objects appear to be effectively a dictionary, that's why you have to use `get` instead of having direct access to the keys

Comment: I'm confused because that's not how in used to dealing with Json... Json is effectively s dict

Comment: yes, this isn't like JSON objects (plain objects), it's a specific object with a provided API